# Sorting Data from a Data Frame to a specific format using Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a got below mentioned Dataframe extracted from an unstructured txt. file. I need it sorted as shown below mentioned example format in the exact order. Please also note that when capturing the date only the date next to(or following) TDY should be captured.

Please note this is a simplified version of the Data frame and the data continues for 3 months.

Dummy initial txt file
https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1CRzCMRo_TV2B-6ZDPA0kb7S7DGuDg7IY

Dataframe

|  | 0 | 5 | 36 | 43 | 79 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TDY | 01JUN2022 | 1.2 | TOM | 1.2 |
| 2 | SPT | 05JUN2022 | 1.4 | 1WK | 1.4 |
| 3 | 2WK | 01JUN2022 | 1.5 | 1MO | 1.6 |
| 4 | 2MO | 06JUN2022 | 1.7 | 3MO | 1.7 |
| 5 | 6MO | 01JUN2022 | 1.4 | 9MO | 1.8 |
| 6 | 1YR | 01JUN2022 | 1.7 | 2YR | 1.3 |
| 7 | 3YR | 01JUN2022 | 1.2 | 4YR | 1.2 |
| 8 | 5YR | 01JUN2022 | 1.4 | 6YR | 1.4 |
| 9 | TDY | 02JUN2022 | 1.2 | TOM | 1.2 |
| 10 | SPT | 02JUN2022 | 1.4 | 1WK | 1.4 |
| 11 | 2WK | 07JUN2022 | 1.5 | 1MO | 1.6 |
| 12 | 2MO | 02JUN2022 | 1.7 | 3MO | 1.7 |
| 13 | 6MO | 02JUN2022 | 1.4 | 9MO | 1.8 |
| 14 | 1YR | 02JUN2022 | 1.7 | 2YR | 1.3 |
| 15 | 3YR | 02JUN2022 | 1.2 | 4YR | 1.2 |
| 16 | 5YR | 07JUN2022 | 1.4 | 6YR | 1.4 |
| 17 | TDY | 03JUN2022 | 1.2 | TOM | 1.2 |
| 18 | SPT | 03JUN2022 | 1.4 | 1WK | 1.4 |
| 19 | 2WK | 03JUN2022 | 1.5 | 1MO | 1.6 |
| 20 | 2MO | 09JUN2022 | 1.7 | 3MO | 1.7 |
| 21 | 6MO | 03JUN2022 | 1.4 | 9MO | 1.8 |
| 22 | 1YR | 02JUN2022 | 1.7 | 2YR | 1.3 |
| 23 | 3YR | 03JUN2022 | 1.2 | 4YR | 1.2 |
| 24 | 5YR | 03JUN2022 | 1.4 | 6YR | 1.4 |

Output required

| Date | TDY | TOM | SPT | 1WK | 2WK | 1MO | 2MO | 3MO | 6MO | 9MO | 1YR | 2YR | 3YR | 4YR | 5YR | 6YR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01JUN2022 | 1.2 | 1.2 | 1.4 | 1.4 | 1.5 | 1.6 | 1.7 | 1.7 | 1.4 | 1.8 | 1.7 | 1.3 | 1.2 | 1.2 | 1.4 | 1.4 |
| 02JUN2022 | 1.2 | 1.2 | 1.4 | 1.4 | 1.5 | 1.6 | 1.7 | 1.7 | 1.4 | 1.8 | 1.7 | 1.3 | 1.2 | 1.2 | 1.4 | 1.4 |
| 03JUN2022 | 1.2 | 1.2 | 1.4 | 1.4 | 1.5 | 1.6 | 1.7 | 1.7 | 1.4 | 1.8 | 1.7 | 1.3 | 1.2 | 1.2 | 1.4 | 1.4 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you wanted to keep that date format or not?

```
dates_df = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[df["0"] == "TDY"]["5"]).reset_index(drop=True)

column_order = ["TDY", "TOM", "SPT", "1WK", "2WK", "1MO", "2MO", "3MO",
                "6MO", "9MO", "1YR", "2YR", "3YR", "4YR", "5YR", "6YR"]

header_df = df[["0", "43"]].melt(value_name="headers")
value_df = df[["36", "79"]].melt(value_name="values")
melted_df = pd.concat([header_df, value_df], axis=1)[["headers", "values"]]

grouped_mapping = melted_df.groupby("headers")["values"].apply(list).to_dict()
grouped_df = pd.DataFrame(grouped_mapping).reindex(columns=column_order)

final_df = pd.merge(dates_df, grouped_df, left_index=True, right_index=True).rename(columns={"5": "Dates"})
print(final_df)

       Dates  TDY  TOM  SPT  1WK  2WK  1MO  ...  9MO  1YR  2YR  3YR  4YR  5YR  6YR
0 2022-06-01  1.2  1.2  1.4  1.4  1.5  1.6  ...  1.8  1.7  1.3  1.2  1.2  1.4  1.4
1 2022-06-02  1.2  1.2  1.4  1.4  1.5  1.6  ...  1.8  1.7  1.3  1.2  1.2  1.4  1.4
2 2022-06-03  1.2  1.2  1.4  1.4  1.5  1.6  ...  1.8  1.7  1.3  1.2  1.2  1.4  1.4
```